# Looping through Django Templates

Tags: python, django, templates

I want to change the classes / attributes of the input fields of a ModelForm, but I'd like to do it from the template if possible.

Below is my solution for this, using the django [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks)

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{form.title|add_class:"form-control"|attr:"placeholder:Title"|attr:"type:text"}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{form.description|add_class:"form-control"|attr:"placeholder:Description"}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{form.author|add_class:"form-control"|attr:"placeholder:Author"}}
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>

</form>
```

My problem, is that this isn't very DRY, and I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this. I know django has looping over forms, but I'm not sure how I can integrate it while modifying the attributes.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the placeholder and store it inside the field's [`help_text` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#help-text). With that out of the way, you can easily loop through the fields like so:

```
{% for field in form %}
<div class="form-group">
    {{ field|add_class:"form-control"|attr:field.help_text }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately it's hard/impossible to use a filter as for the second argument, so you will need to set `help_text` to `'placeholder:%s'` where `%s` is your desired value.

---

If you're using a regular form, then set `help_text` in the constructor. But if you're using model form, I think it would be best to create a new template tag that can create the `'placeholder:%s'` string for you from the field title:

```
@register.assignment_tag
def get_placeholder_arg(field):
    return 'placeholder:%s' % field.label
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
{% for field in form %}
{% get_placeholder_arg field as arg %}
<div class="form-group">
    {{ field|add_class:"form-control"|attr:arg }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

See [the django documentation on custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/) for details.

Comment: The type field was for testing and I don't need it, and the solution looks really good, I'm just curious as to how I'll pass the string to the help text? I'd like to control it from the template if possible, so all front end properties will be clear by looking at the template

Comment: Updated the answer. It's really lame that in django you can't set variables in templates without the use of a tags. Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I am looking for! Thanks!